# phpmyadmin login only local area network

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I have a question about logining at phpmyadmin.

I would like to show phpmyadmin log in page ONLY local area network 
connection PCs and cellphone.

Here is my info.

CentOS 7.2
phpmyadmin 4.4.15.8
Apache 2.4.6
PHP 7.0.13
MariaDB 10.1.19
my server's pravate ip adress is 192.168.0.12
my routor is 192.168.0.1

Here is my current code (which all PC and device can see phpadmin login page.)
/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf

```html
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
      Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the lines of Apache 2.4 and phpMyAdmin directory by your area network :

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
      Require local
      Require ip 192.168.1 #HERE put your network address
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Or to be even more specific

```
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1.100
Require ip 192.168.1.101
```